# how to understand all multiverses in marvel universe?

Tags: marvel, parallel-universe

I am new to Marvel Comics.

I know there is a universe in which Yggdrasill connects 9 Realms. So is that it? 
Are there only 9 Realms in this universe? Or is Yggdrasill just a portion of this universe ?

Is there any link where I can see all the other multiverses if they exist?

Comment: "multiverses in marvel universe" — that would be "universes in Marvel multiverse". A multiverse is made up of multiple universes. ("Uni" means "one". "Multi" means "many".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Realm isn't quite the same as a universe. One universe has 9 Realms and many more dimensions.

## Realms

In Marvel terms, the 616 universe (which is where the main stories were set, before the current *Secret Wars* storyline) has 9 Realms:

[image: 9 realms of Marvel]

- Alfheim - home of the light elves
- Nidavellir - home of the dwarves
- Jotunheim - home of the giants
- Svatalfheim - home of the dark elves
- Hel - the realm of the dead
- Muspelheim - home of the demons
- Vanaheim - home of the Vanir
- Midgard - where the humans live.
- Asgard - home of Thor etc..

Our realm is Midgard. This is pretty much the Norse mythology view of things. 
Illustrated here in an old Thor comic:

[image]

However, during *Original Sin*, a tenth was added:

- Heven - home of the Angels.

Here's a map from *Thor v4* #7, with Ygdrassil in:

[image]

## Other Dimensions

On top of that you have other dimensions such as Limbo (e.g. Magik of the X-Men) and other demon specific realms (from Doctor Strange stories). See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Comics_dimensions) for a list. Highlights include:

- Limbo - Home of Belasco, featured in the X-Men books and linked to Magik
- The Mojoverse - home of the X-Men villain Mojo
- The Microverse - where Ant Man shrinks to
- The Negative Zone - featured prominently in Fantastic Four books

(The "realms" of the Thor books are basically interconnected dimensions)

As to how many universes in the multiverse - see [How many Marvel Earths (Universes) are there?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89740/how-many-marvel-earths-universes-are-there?rq=1).