# How did Peter Parker travel to high school?

Tags: marvel, comics, spider-man

After becoming Spider-Man, did the teenaged Peter still ride the bus to Midtown High School, or did he start web-slinging to get there?  Was this ever established in the comics?

While I am interested in any depictions of such travel, I am primarily interested in the main universe of Earth-616, not the alternate universes, nor any of the non-Peter Spider-Men, nor any version where he is no longer in high school.

Comment: This seems like a rather broad set of answers are possible. As many comics and movies will differ etc...

Comment: Additionally, I assume the web-slinging just becomes an additional mode of travel that he may use *sometimes*. He probably doesn't want to blow his cover though.

Comment: Just opinion but probably to protect his identity he would try to maintain his status as a student and ride the bus.

Comment: Exactly!  AFAIK they just don't depict it, so we can assume it's the boring answer. I expect that it would get old if he had to repeatedly explain how he missed the bus and still made it to school on time...  And knowing that the upcoming movie will finally show him in high school, maybe we'll get some canonical answers there.

Comment: Maybe you should define it down to the main continuity? As there are several multiverses where the Spiderman could be doing different things. Such as Indian Spiderman on his way to meet his uncle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMO2u.jpg

Comment: I guess you could choose from a [few of these](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89740/how-many-marvel-earths-universes-are-there)?

Comment: This also reeks of not even the most basic research. Have you bothered to read a single Spider-man comic, or watch a single one of the movies? Come on man, do some research.

Comment: @JDoe Well a quick google lead to nothing, so it seems like there might be some hidden gems as to how he's getting to school

Comment: Yes, having googled the original question, this now turns up as the first result, which indicates that nobody else has asked it.  My collection of Spider-man comics mostly is from the 90's, where he was no longer in school, and primarily concerned with clones and fighting symbiotes, so there were no answers there.

Comment: @JDoe - If you think the question is so trivial to answer,  may I suggest you answer it.

Comment: How does Peter Parker get to school? Practice!

Comment: @PaulD: But only if he's going to Carnegie Mellon.

Comment: In *Avengers: Infinity War*, he's riding a school bus over a bridge (the Brooklyn Bridge? My New York geography is not great) when Ebony Maw's ship first appears.

Comment: Web fluild is a limited resource that he makes and refills in his laboratory.  Using it up willy nilly would not be practical.

Answer (score 5):

In [Peter Parker, The Spectacular Spider-Man: The Vulture Is a Bird of Prey](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker,_The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_Vol_1_4), Peter wakes up late and can't get *on* the bus like he wanted to:

[image: Peter: "Got less than a minute to catch my bus!"]

He ends up webslinging on*to* the bus roof as Spiderman but then gets knocked off by a branch, forcing him to have to find his way to school:

[image]

At this point he is in college and the bus is a double decker public one, not a school bus. He ends up being late for class.

Comment: The question specifically states that the asker is not interested in post-high school. As such, this doesn't really answer the question on whether he caught the bus to *high school*.

Comment: @Gnemlock The question says "I am interested in any depictions of such travel". The more specific focus was added after the question was closed in order to get it reopened. Still, I think that it is pretty relevant even to the question of what he did in high school: if snow's out, it's going to be just as unpleasant webslinging to school and he's still going to have to change.

Comment: I would agree if the scope was narrowed after the fact, but the restrictions that disclude your answer were made almost two years prior to your answer. The rest of your argument is just speculation on what you think he would do.

Answer (score 2):

#### It seems the [Earth-616](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-616) version of Peter generally *walked* the distance between his home and [Midtown High School](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Midtown_High_School).

[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_4)

[image]

[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #8](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_8)

[image]

[Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #19](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_19)

[image]

He was never shown riding a school bus during that period, nor did he appear to make a habit of traversing that distance on weblines, which makes sense, since the distance between his home and Midtown High was a mere three blocks according to [Amazing Spider-Man Annual Vol 1 #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Annual_Vol_1_1).

[image]