# Is the mainstream Marvel universe still referred to as Earth-616 after Secret Wars (2015)?

Tags: marvel, comics, secret-wars-2015

As described in [How many Marvel Earths (Universes) are there?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89740/13217), there used to be lots of Marvel universes, but *Secret Wars* combined them all into one (aside from the cinematic universes, which were untouched and are largely ignored by the comics). From KutuluMike's answer:

> Technically, as of right now, there are very few Marvel universes. The recently released Secret Wars (the 2015 one, not to be confused with the one from 1984) event has effectively erased all numbered comic-book universes from existence, leaving only Battleworld. Once that event series is over, in theory there will only be 1 comics universe.

Is this singular remaining comics universe (the new "mainstream" universe) still referred to as Earth-616, despite being the only-ish universe still around? Or is that designation no longer used and it's called something else?

I'm mostly interested in in-universe designations, but would welcome out-of-universe designations as supplementary information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, I believe Earth-616 is no longer supposed to be referred to as such. In theory, the multiverse was supposed to be wiped out, with the elimination of the Ultimate Marvel universe, and the elimination of alternate universes for the various members of the Squadron Supreme.

However, several books have continued as if *most* of the multiverse was still intact. Shortly after *Secret Wars*, we had the *Spider-Women* crossover, running through *Spider-Woman*, *Spider-Gwen*, and *Silk*. *Spider-Gwen* and *Spider-Man: Renew Your Vows* clearly take place in alternate universes.

In the *Spider-Women* crossover event, the main Marvel U was still referred to as Earth-616:

[image: Earth-616 in Spider-Women Alpha 1]

The slightly more recent crossover between Spider-Man (Miles) and Spider-Gwen (titled "Sitting in a Tree") sees Earth-65 (it's Spider-Gwen's home reality):

[image: Earth-65 (Spider-Gwen 18)]

Earth-8 (home of one Amazing Spider-Ham, at least):

[image: Earth-8 (Spider-Gwen 18)]

And what was formerly called Earth-616:

[image: FKA Earth-616 (Spider-Gwen 17)]

In fact, in the latest issue of *Spider-Gwen* (30), it's implied that Earth-65's Gwen met what's apparently the Earth-616 Gwen prior to her death, causing the "creation" of an Earth-617:

[image: Earth-616.525 (Spider-Gwen 30)][image: Earth-617 (Spider-Gwen 30)]

Based on the "Formerly Known as" crack, I don't think there's a clear way to refer to the "prime" version of the Marvel U yet. I believe that *Spider-Gwen* is the main title dealing with the multiverse at this point, and (as you can see) that team doesn't use a new reference for the main Marvel U.

Comment: @thunderforge gwen's. I don't think there is any intention of only having a single universe, xmen blue has the goblin queen summon various alternate versions of the xmen, and attempt to summon alternate versions of herself. Presumably deadpool kills the marvel universe again is also in an alternate universe.